# Sticky Nav active button flashing using Bootstrap template

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm having issues when I scroll. The active button on Nav is flashing/flickering. I used a template from Git called Bootstrap Agency.

I'm not that great with JS but I know the issue is in the following JS code from doing some research. Any help on how to stop this flickering would be much appreciated!

```js
$(function() {
  $('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
    var $anchor = $(this);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
      scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});

// Highlight the top nav as scrolling occurs
$('body').scrollspy({
  target: '.navbar-fixed-top'
})

// Closes the Responsive Menu on Menu Item Click
$('.navbar-collapse ul li a').click(function() {
  $('.navbar-toggle:visible').click();
});
```

here is the HTML/CSS:

```
  <!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <style>-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

Toggle navigation

```
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="hidden">
                    <a href="#page-top"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#corso"><em>Why CorsoCoin?</em></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#ethos">Ethos</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#roadmap">Roadmap</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#socials">Socials</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Whitepaper</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">We Are Hiring?</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Can you please add the relevant HTML and CSS to the question so we can see a working example of the issue, and the context you're working in. Also, which version of jQuery are you using? `bind()` has been deprecated for a *long* time.

Comment: Sorry I sorted that, i am unsure, i don't usually use js or jquery so have 0 knowledge in it, just using a template i found.